# ios - Applications UI gets block for some time interval when first time pushing view controller to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

In my application when i am pushing a view controller first time, The UI will block for few seconds. I am really confused, Can any one help me out please to fix this issue. or Any suggestion is appreciated ...

Relevant Code

```
 @IBAction func didTapEditButton(sender: AnyObject){
    let editProfileViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EditProfileViewController") as? EditProfileViewController
    if let editProfileViewController = editProfileViewController
    {
        editProfileViewController.userName = userName
        navigationController?.pushViewController(editProfileViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us some code first, and maybe we can help...

Comment: @IBAction func didTapEditButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let editProfileViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EditProfileViewController") as? EditProfileViewController
   if let editProfileViewController = editProfileViewController {
            editProfileViewController.userName = userName
            navigationController?.pushViewController(editProfileViewController, animated: true)
   }

Comment: This code snippet what , I have used while pushing view controller

Comment: Are you testing on simulator or a real device?

Comment: @Siddu Halake : Are you performing any heavy operation in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear of EditProfileViewController ???

Comment: @ Laffen i was tested this code in simulator as well device. But i faced same issue

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari : Even i commented every thing from ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear what i had wrote, But still i have been facing same problem